# The total number of points of $\mathbb{R}$ at which $f$ attains a local extremum

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) = \vert x^2-25 \vert$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. The total number of points of $\mathbb{R}$ at which $f$ attains a local extremum is

$A$. $1$

$B$. $2$

$C$. $3$

$D$. $4$

What I was thinking where $f'(x)=0$. but this only gives you $x=0$. Now here I'm stuck. Help me!

Comment: Where is $f'$ defined?

Comment: $f'$ is not defined somewhere !
For example consider $x=0$ as a local minimum for $y=|x|$.

Comment: You can draw this function graph easily ...

Comment: @ Fardad Pouran : Yes! The $f'$ is not defined for $x$=$5$ and $-5$

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/swBBU.jpg

Comment: What could be the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that

> a function can have a relative maximum or relative minimum only at those numbers in its domain at which the derivative is undefined or is zero (these numbers are called critical points).

Notice that $f'(x) = \begin{cases} -2x & x \in (-5, 5) \\ 2x & x \in (-\infty, -5) \cup (5, \infty) \\ \text{DNE} & x = -5, 5 \end{cases}$

Notice that if we consider $f'$ on the domain in which it is defined, $f'(x) = 0$ means $x = 0$.

So our critical points are $x = -5, 0, 5$. Hence your answer (d) is out of the question since there are at most 3 local extremum.

Now we check each point one by one:

1. ($x = 5$): $f(5) = 0$ and $f(5) \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in [4, 6]$.
2. ($x = 0$): $f(0) = 25$ and $f(0) \geq f(x)$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$.
3. ($x = -5$): $f(-5) = 0$ and $f(-5) \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in [-6, -4]$. Here you could notice that $f$ is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis and refer to the case where $x = 5$.

Hence we have 3 local extrema. This should have been obvious from looking at the graph, which is simple enough to draw pretty quickly!